# Vectorizing a Nested Loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am looking to vectorize a nested loop, which will work on a list of 300,000 lists, with each of these lists containing 3 values. The nested loop compares the values of each of the lists with the corresponding values in the other lists, and will only append the list indices which have corresponding values having a maximum difference of 0.1 between them. Thus, a list containing [0.234, 0.456, 0.567] and a list containing [0.246, 0.479, 0.580] would fall in this category, since their corresponding values (i.e. 0.234 and 0.246; 0.456 and 0.479; 0.567 and 0.580) have a difference of less than 0.1 between them.

I currently use the following nested loop to do this, but it would currently take approximately 58 hours to complete (a total of 90 trillion iterations);

```
import numpy as np
variable = np.random.random((300000,3)).tolist()
out1=list()
out2=list()
for i in range(0:300000):
    for j in range(0:300000):
        if ((i<j) and ((abs(variable[i][0]-variable[j][0]))<0.1) and ((abs(variable[i][1]-variable[j] [1]))<0.1) and ((abs(variable[i][2]-variable[j][2]))<0.1)):
        out1.append(i)  
        out2.append(j)
```

Comment: Your `variable` is random, is it just for the example, or are you actually simulating something?

Comment: Yes it's just for the example - in reality I have a list of lists, generated via a simulation, which actually has data falling within the threshold I mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into scipy.spatial; it has a lot of functionality for solving such spatial queries efficiently; [KDTrees](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs) in particular, ie:

```
import scipy.spatial
out = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(variable).query_pairs(r=0.1, p=np.infinity)
```

Comment: Tried this out; it's returning "A float is required". I'm assuming it's something simple; thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the docs; they arnt particularly clear on this subject. Try the edit. The 'infinity-norm' should boil down to the metric you are looking for; maximum absolute value of any of the components.

Comment: note that for the sake of efficiency, it is best to forego lists entirely in favor of ndarrays. That applies to your input, but also the output; note that you can add the output_type='ndarray' kwarg to this call.

Comment: After changing np.infinity to np.infty, it worked well, but after a few minutes of running on 300,000 lists it put forth a "Killed" message, which turns out to be a memory issue once again. How do you add the output_type kwarg?

Comment: See the provided link in my post for the exact signature. The reason you are getting the memory error still is because the number of pairs for the data you are generating is huge; all points generated by np.random.random lie in a unit cube, so the number of neighbors within a r=0.1 box is still enormous. Are you sure this is actually representative of your true data?

Comment: This solved the problem entirely - the entire function is now running in around 30 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Convert to NumPy array to make it easier to use NumPy funcs thereafter. Then, two approaches could be suggested.

**Approach #1**

NumPy broadcasting could be used to extend those to 3D arrays and perform the operations in a vectorized manner. Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
th = 0.1 # Threshold
arr = np.asarray(variable)
out1,out2 = np.where(np.triu((np.abs(arr[:,None,:] - arr) < th).all(-1),1))
```

**Approach #2**

Alternative implementation with focus on memory efficiency that uses selective indices that would be responsible for such iterations  -

```
th = 0.1 # Threshold
arr = np.asarray(variable)
R,C = np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0],1)
mask = (np.abs(arr[R] - arr[C])<th).all(-1)
out1,out2 = R[mask], C[mask]
```

Comment: That would work if you had a terabyte of ram, yes :)

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn `Approach #2` might be less heavy :)

Comment: tried this, but getting and out of memory error; tried it again with just 30,000 lists and still running; I'm guessing it's still going to take rather long? Running on 256Gb RAM

Comment: @JBorg Did you try `Approach #2`? Also, do try `KDTrees` based solution as suggested by @Eelco Hoogendoorn.

Comment: Still reporting a Memory Error with 300,000 lists for Approach #2, and ran in about 5-7 minutes with 30,000 lists. Running again to check actual time. Thanks for your replies, by the way! :)